# How can I limit the input number range?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, input

I would like to limit the input number that can go up to the current year, the user cannot enter a year higher than the current one. How can I do it?

My code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="season.Year" type="number" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use normal HTML input attributes such as `min` and `max`:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="season.Year" type="number" min="1" max="5"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` property for these. Since you are using a `number` type, just add `min` attribute:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="season.Year" type="number" min="2018"></ion-input>
```

Examples:

```
  Enter a date before 1980-01-01:
  <input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">

  Enter a date after 2000-01-01:
  <input type="date" name="bday" min="2000-01-02">

  Quantity (between 1 and 5):
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to hard core the max value.

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="season.Year" type="number" min="19XX" max="2018"></ion-input>
```

If you dont want to hard core the current year you can use Date class or use moment.js to fetch the current year and bind the year in html as follows.

```
 <ion-input [(ngModel)]="season.Year" type="number" min="19XX" max="{{maxyear}}"></ion-input>
```